# How do I pass Branch Name to an MSBuild script in TeamCity?

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I've got TeamCity building a configuration across multiple Mercurial branches. As part of the build process, I want to name some output based on the branch being built from.

I've tried using `$(TEAMCITY_BUILD_BRANCH)`, to try to obtain the `teamcity.build.branch` property from TeamCity, but I only get an empty string. I successfully used `$(BUILD_NUMBER)` to get the `build.number` property into the script, so I'm a little confused to what is required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a build parameter:

```
system.branch_name = %teamcity.build.vcs.branch.Your_Project%
```

Any non-alpha-numerical chars in the project name should be replaced by "_".
In your msbuild use `$(branch_name)` to reference the parameter.

Works like charm :-)

Comment: tried it - it gets \refs\head\whatever, where 'whatever' is an actual branch name

Comment: @chester89 You can use brackets to specify name submatch: for example `refs/head/(master)`, `refs/head/release/(*)` or `refs/head/(feature/*)` ... to get "master", "1.2.3", and "feature/some-name" respectively.

Comment: while using the brackets around the branch name made only the branch name (without "refs/head/") appear in the TeamCity UI, the %teamcity.build.vcs.branch.Your_Project% parameter still gets resolved to a value that includes refs/heads. I'm on version 8.0.6 of TeamCity.

Comment: @Alexander Marinov: How can I pass the branch name to a script that needs to be run from teamcity as a build step

Answer (score 2):

$(vcsroot_url) if you have only one vcs root attached to build configuration.

If this is not what you want - try to get all known properties with as described here:
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Predefined+Build+Parameters

Reference-only Server Properties:

> You can get the full set of reference-only server properties by adding
>   system.teamcity.debug.dump.parameters property to the build
>   configuration and examining "Available reference-only server
>   properties" section in the build log.

UPD: Also you can check this ["what's new" link](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/What%27s+New+in+TeamCity+7.1#What%27sNewinTeamCity7.1-VCSbranchparameter).

> VCS branch parameter For Git and Mercurial, TeamCity provides
>   additional build parameters with names of VCS branches known at the
>   moment of build starting. If a build took a revision from the
>   refs/heads/bugfix branch, TeamCity will add a configuration parameter
>   with the following name: teamcity.build.vcs.branch.<simplified VCS
>   root name>=refs/heads/bugfix
>
> Where  is the name of the VCS root where all
>   non-alpha numeric characters are replaced with _.

According to this - you should be able to access branch as following msbuild variable
$(teamcity_build_vcs_branch_).

Hope this time I understood your issue properly.

PS: Sorry for initial misguiding - I didn't know about such subtle differences between DVCS and CVCS in TeamCity. Anyway - my initial answer could also help you - you can get all variables and then find exact var name with proper data you want

Comment: @Alexy I'm using Mercurial, so the branch name isn't a URL, but a name within the repository. I don't quite understand what is required to reference the given build parameter in an MSBuild script.

Comment: If you build with TeamCity - it will emit some of it's own environment variables to msbuild context, and you can access it like it your own previously defined properties. It's same way BUILD.NUMBER from TeamCity become $(BUILD_NUMBER) available to your msbuild script. Teamcity usually emits many usefull info - you can check docs for full details. As soon as you asked about accessing branch name - I thought that you can extract it from vcs url. Unfortunately - I don't have Teamcity with Mercurual as VCS, only svn here. I found some more clarifications on that and will append it to my answer

Comment: I've tried `$(teamcity_build_vcs_branch_)`, both upper and lower case, with and without the trailing underscore: none of these have worked, whilst $(BUILD_NUMBER) still functions.

Comment: just noticed - last part of variable was eaten by sanitizer
$(teamcity_build_vcs_branch_your-vcsroot-name-here).
Also "You can get the full set of reference-only server properties by adding system.teamcity.debug.dump.parameters property to the build configuration and examining "Available reference-only server properties" section in the build log."